# Would it be possible to display the list of users?

Tags: batch-file

http://pastebin.com/0fP0kiJC

Batch file

Hi, I would like to allow users to see what users have logged into the system, could it be possible for it to read off the listed users in the Accounts.UF file it makes and display them? If so, it would be a great help. All of my attempts didnt seem to work.

To test fix it,save it as a Batch file and run it.

Comment: Could you please include information and/or an example of the Accounts.UF file that you want to parse? That is easier than interpreting the whole batch file that you posted.

Comment: To test fix it,save it as a Batch file and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> could it be possible for it to read off the listed users in the Accounts.UF file it makes and display them?

You can use the following line in your batch script:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%u IN (`FINDSTR "^username[^;]*$" %~dp0Accounts.uf`) DO ECHO %%u
```

This assumes that you do not allow usernames with a `;`, but your batch script does not seem to check for invalid usernames in the first place.